# Clipping raster never maintains extent (extra pixels outside of extent)

Tags: raster, clip, extents

The problem:

I try to clip an elevation raster to a polygon extent (the red outline), but no matter what setting I tweak or work-around I try, this is always the result.

[image: The clipping raster output always results in this extra pixels in the upper-right corner.]

I've tried:

- Clip Raster
- Extract by mask
- Raster calculator
- SetNull
- Extract by attribute
- Different environment settings

I've made sure that the coordinate system are the same for all layers, as well as the cell size for the rasters, but to no avail.

Any magician out there that knowns what is going on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Raster is a rectangle with fixed number of rows and columns like a chess board. The area between the clipping polygon and raster boundaries is filled with nodata pixels.

Comment: Maybe post a new question asking how to hid the NoData pixels from the display in your specific software application?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user30184. I understand that part. What I don't understand is why only the top-right corner of the clipped raster leaks out of the clipping extent but the rest of the output is perfectly within it.

Comment: I just discovered something (for the record: I'm using ArcGIS Pro): If I set the output location of the Clip Raster tool to the geodatabase, the extra pixels do not appear, but when I save the output outside of the geodatabase, then this problem occurs. What could that be all about?

Comment: I have a feeling that coordinate systems have something to do with the issue even you mentioned that the raster and the clipping polygon are using the same crs. Difficult to say more without a re-producible test case with sample data.

Comment: @FranciscoJavierAriQuintana Your polygon doesn't have straight edges. The raster is a fixed set of rows and columns so has straight edges. If it doesn't match, it is likely the square is not actually a square. If you have to use this shape exactly, you'll have to sacrifice the last column of pixels which will leave a missing gap at the bottom right corner